# Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $\{(x,y,z)\mid 2x^2-8y^2-9z^2\le 1\}$

Why is this not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

I know the zero vector is in this set because $ 2(0) - 8(0) - 9(0) \le 1$

But I can't seem to verify if the set is closed under linear combination.

Note: This is NOT for a test/marked assignment, simply practice.

Comment: When is $t\cdot(x,y,z)$ in the set for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You can see $v=(\frac12,0,0)$ is in that set, but $2v$ is not.

Comment: What happens if you choose two elements that are both equal to 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\displaystyle v=\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,0\right)$ is a vector in this collection. Is $2\cdot v$ in this collection?

Answer (score 1):

It is not closed by scalar multiplication. See that $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2},0,0\right)$ is in the set, but, for instance, $100 \cdot \left (\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, 0, 0\right)$ is not.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's because it's not under R^n by scalar multiplication. If u choose

2(1)-8(1)-9(1) = -15

And if u then multiply by a scalar -1, you get 15 which is not defined in the collection.

Comment: This argument is invalid, because $(-1)^2=1$. You have to multiply the arguments, not the equation.